# Code from react-dnd docs

Tags: reactjs

What the hell is going on in this code? It's from react-dnd docs. Observer is null and not a function, how can you make observer o (don't even know what 'o' stands for) and then call a function observer(knightPosition).

```
let knightPosition = [0, 0];
let observer = null;

function emitChange() {
  observer(knightPosition);
}

export function observe(o) {
  observer = o;
  emitChange();
}

export function moveKnight(toX, toY) {
  knightPosition = [toX, toY];
  emitChange();
}


observe(knightPosition => {
  render(
    <Board knightPosition={knightPosition} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
});
```

Comment: `o` is the argument that `observe` function receives which in this case is an arrow function with render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What React-DND is trying to achieve here is a Redux like flow where a global state can be changed and accessed from inside the component.

`knightPosition` is the variable that is globally kept in the store which has to be changed. When the variable changes, we have to trigger a change (`emitChange` function) which can update the React DOM. You can look at the example with comments for more explanation.

```js
let knightPosition = 0;
let observer = null;

function Board(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.knightPosition}</p>
      <button onClick={(e)=>moveKnight(10)}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function moveKnight(value) { //Changes the knightPosition value
  knightPosition = value;  
  emitChange();
}

function emitChange() {
  observer(knightPosition);  // Calls the function reference it received with current knightPosition value
}

function observe(o) {  //Sets the function reference it receives to observer variable. 
  observer = o;
  emitChange();
}

function renderFunction(knightPosition) { //Just renders to DOM
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Board knightPosition={knightPosition} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}

observe(renderFunction);  //Passing a reference of renderFunction to observe
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I have changed `knightPostion` variable from array to a variable for simplification.

Comment: I am still extremely confused by this code, and have several questions about your answer. What is the significance of the name `observe` and `observer`? Does the initial `observer` need to equal `null`, or could it have been established with `let observer;`? Why does `renderFunction()` need to call `ReactDOM.render()`; isn't the point of React to have `setState` re-render the DOM when a value is changed? Why is `emitChange()` called from both `moveKnight()` and `observe()`? This whole block of code is making me question if I understand React at all.